# R - split list and marge same table

Tags: r

Sorry, the title may not describe well

I have a dataframe form google history

original

```
> head(testAC)
  latitudeE7 longitudeE7                       activity
1  247915291  1209946249                         NULL
2  248033293  1209803613                         NULL
3  248033293  1209803613         1505536182769, IN_VEHICLE, STILL, UNKNOWN, 54, 31, 15
```

result

```
> head(testAC)
  latitudeE7|longitudeE7| activityTime|mainactivity| speed
1  247915291| 1209946249|             |    NULL    |
2  248033293| 1209803613|             |    NULL    |
3  248033293| 1209803613|1505536182769| IN_VEHICLE |   54
4  248033293| 1209803613|1505536182769|    STILL   |   31
5  248033293| 1209803613|1505536182769|   UNKNOWN  |   15
```

Original line 3, become result 3 to 5 lines

I only know do.call ("rbind", testAC$activity),

But just split the activity, latitudeE7 and longitudeE7 disappeared

```
> do.call ("rbind", testAC$activity)
    timestampMs                activity
1 1505536182769       IN_VEHICLE, STILL, UNKNOWN, 54, 31, 15
2 1505536077547   IN_VEHICLE, UNKNOWN, ON_BICYCLE, STILL, 64, 23, 8, 5
```

I look for two days, but may not keyword, can not find

Can anyone explain how to do what I want?

Thank you

I have a Rdata uploaded on Google Drive, maybe know more about it
[google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8EpbEr2pFK5uPT-TnvK03qzfHKb-2MH/view)

Comment: Please don't post links to data; instead edit your question with the results of calling `dput` on the object in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(plyr)
cbind(dataAC[, 1:2], ldply(lapply(dataAC$activity, function(x) if (!is.null(x)) unlist(lapply(x, unlist)) else NA), rbind))
```

It will give you a dataframe instead of nested lists, and then you can reshape it however you want

```
  latitudeE7 longitudeE7    1   timestampMs activity.type1 activity.type2 activity.type3 activity.confidence1 activity.confidence2
1  247915291  1209946249 <NA>          <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>
2  248033293  1209803613 <NA>          <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>
3  248033293  1209803613 <NA> 1505536182769     IN_VEHICLE          STILL        UNKNOWN                   54                   31
4  248002555  1209895254 <NA> 1505536077547     IN_VEHICLE        UNKNOWN     ON_BICYCLE                   64                   23
5  247966714  1209957315 <NA> 1505535932508     IN_VEHICLE     ON_BICYCLE           <NA>                   54                   46
6  247966714  1209957315 <NA> 1505535825664           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>
  activity.confidence3 activity.type4 activity.confidence4 activity.type activity.confidence
1                 <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>          <NA>                <NA>
2                 <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>          <NA>                <NA>
3                   15           <NA>                 <NA>          <NA>                <NA>
4                    8          STILL                    5          <NA>                <NA>
5                 <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>          <NA>                <NA>
6                 <NA>           <NA>                 <NA>       TILTING                 100
```